# Adding a class and ID to headers using Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, zendesk

The way that Zendesk's Help Centre works is by printing all the sections onto the page without giving them any unique identifier, so it's a pain if you want to implement any sort of scrollspy (updating a sidenav with where you are on the page), and most importantly anchors so that the sidenav actually works.

I'm not that technical and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to add an ID & class to a series of headers using JS?

I'm thinking for each `h2` in `section-tree-with-article`, adding a unique ID, and a class that matches the h2's text?

Any thoughts?

[image: Help Centre]

[image: Source code]

Comment: You should paste your code into the question as images of the code do not permit experts to find what they need to help you. Use the [edit] button to improve your question. You might find [ask] helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select all the `h2` elements, iterate through them and set a `class` as well as an `id` with each iteration.

I've simple set the `innerHTML` as the `class`. You can modify it according to your use case.

```js
var headers = document.querySelectorAll("div.section-tree-with-article h2");

headers.forEach(function(header, idx) {
  header.className = header.textContent.replace(/\s/g, "-");      //You can modify this accordingly
  header.id = "uniqueID" + idx;            //And similarily the uniqueID
})
```

```html
<div class="section-tree-with-article">
  <ul>
    <li class="section">
      <h2>Admin 0</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="section">
      <h2>Admin 1</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="section">
      <h2>Admin 2</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="section">
      <h2>Admin 3 4 5</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="section">
      <h2>Admin 4</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the same solution in jquery:

```
$("div.section-tree-with-article h2").each(function(index, value){
    var classToAdd = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr('class', classToAdd);
    $(this).attr('id', "uniqueID" + index);
})
```

Comment: Just noticed, because the text contains spaces, it's added multiple classes, can these spaces be replaced for `-`s? 

Preferably in jquery?

Comment: @tectomics I've edited the answer accordingly. Check and confirm if it's working for you.

Comment: [It does, but only for h2s with less than 3 words.](https://s30.postimg.org/blobs6u5t/Screen_Shot_2017_01_12_at_10_43_51.png)

Cheers for you help here again.

Comment: @tectomics Edited again. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Don't apologise, you've done me such a huge favour! Thank you so much! 
: )

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer does not address your request for a JavaScript solution, I recommend instead using the Help Center's built-in templating system to iterate on the elements and add classes, directly in the html files. Please note that this is only available in the "Professional" and "Enterprise" Zendesk plans.

This example is probably not the best, since you will end up with spaces or other unusable characters in the value of the `h2` elements' `class` attribute (it will replace `{{name}}` with the section's name), but I hope it will give you an idea of how this works, and how you might use it to achieve a solution.

```
<div class="section-tree-with-article">
  <ul>
    {{#each sections}}
      <li class="section">
        <h2 class="{{name}}" id="{{id}}">{{name}}</h2>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

will end up something like this:

```
<div class="section-tree-with-article">
  <ul>
    <li class="section">
      <h2 class="Admin and Settings" id="12345">Admin and Settings</h2>
    </li>
    <li class="section">
      <h2 class="Getting Started" id="45678">Getting Started</h2>
    </li>
    ...[more sections]...
  </ul>
</div>
```

More info on Help Center templating here:
https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/216367358-Help-Center-templating-cookbook-Professional-and-Enterprise-